# installing segmentation on python

Tags: python

I want to install segmentation in python but when I send command I get this error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting segmentation
  Using cached segmentation-0.2.2.tar.gz (132 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6jdotxrl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6jdotxrl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6jdotxrl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\arian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6jdotxrl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I test this command (`pip install segmentation`) and I think it install correctly.

OS: Windows 10

Python version: 3.12

Comment: my python version : 3.12

Comment: It looks like the package isn't installing its build requirements as it should.  Try running `pip install numpy` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install numpy and cython first `pip install numpy cython` and then run `pip install segmentation` as written in their doc.

It's due to the import at the beginning of the `setup.py` [file](https://github.com/BooneAndrewsLab/segmentation/blob/a1cc8a2ff2e7283045b21c7943fe12c6504deb58/setup.py). As this file is loaded by pip when you run `pip install segmentation`, you have to install dependencies before installing the main package:

```py
import numpy as np
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from setuptools import setup, Extension
```

*edit*: I think even with the previous command, you'll have some matters. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/BooneAndrewsLab/segmentation/issues/4) concerning installation. As the last commit is two years old, you should try with older numpy and cython version by writting `pip install numpy==xx.xx cython==yy` with xx and yy the older versions. And you'll have to try versions.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received indicates that there's a problem installing the 'segmentation' package because your system is missing a required library called 'numpy'. To fix this issue, you need to first install 'numpy'. Once installed, you should install the 'segmentation' package without any issues.
Try by following command `pip install numpy` and then try `pip install segmentation`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure pip, wheels and setup tools are up-to-date, and then install the package.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
```

2. Check if you are able to install packages in a virtual environment.

```bash
python -m venv env   # creates a virtual environment
source env/Scripts/activate  # activates the environment
pip install numpy  # install the package
```

3. If the above does not work, install using -pre flag: `pip install numpy --pre`

- --pre flag include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.